# Replacement for thread.start() and thread.abort()

Tags: vb.net

I need to display a form for some amount of time - basically a "please wait, loading" form with progress bar. When certain operation completes, I want this window to disappear. Here's my try at it:

```
 If IsNothing(mlLabels) Or mblnIsLoading Then Exit Sub
        If mstrPrinterA.Equals(Me.cmbPrinters.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim th As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf WaitPrinter)
        th.Start()
        If mlLabels.IsPrinterOnLine(Me.cmbPrinters.Text) Then
            Me.cmbPrinters.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Green
        Else
            Me.cmbPrinters.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        End If
        th.Abort()
        Do While th.IsAlive

        Loop
        th = Nothing
        mstrPrinterA = Me.cmbPrinters.Text

Private Sub WaitPrinter()
        Dim fw As New FormWaiting
        fw.ShowDialog()
        fw = Nothing
End Sub
```

However, I then read that using `Thread.Start()` and `Thread.Abort()` is not considered a good practice. Is there another way I can do that?

Comment: `Thread.Start()` is perfectly fine to do. `Thread.Abort()` is disastrous. Whenever you abort a thread you are forcibly ending a thread and can leave the run-time's state in an undefined state. This can then mean that all remaining threads won't execute properly. The only time you should ever call `Thread.Abort()` is when you are trying to crash out of your program.

Comment: Also, you should never create, access or update a UI element from a non-UI thread. So calling `New FormWaiting` from a new thread is bad also. It's the code that is "loading" that should be running on a background thread - not your UI.

Comment: And finally `Do While th.IsAlive : Loop` could lock up your code if the `th` thread catches the `ThreadAbortException` and prevents the thread from actually aborting. You've got some bad code on many levels.

Comment: What you should do is create and show that form as a modal dialogue on the UI thread and pass it a delegate to the method to be executed.  It can then execute that method on a secondary thread and close itself when the method completes.

Comment: A more craftsman approach woule be to create a global boolean variable to be set/unset outside of the thread. The thread would be looping based on the boolean variable set elsewhere. Like "While var = true     ... End while".

Comment: Use that form's BeginInvoke() method to call its Close() method.  Ends the thread as well, no need for abort.  Do beware that displaying UI on a worker thread is quite risky, you have to keep it very simple to avoid the SystemEvents class from causing deadlock.  Just a single Label is okay.  Consider that a user isn't going to be very interested in this, not that much fun watching grass grow.  You'd be much better off by simply hiding the main window and reporting completion with a NotifyIcon.ShowBalloon() call.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of what I described in my comment above.  Create a WinForms project with two forms, adding a `Button` to `Form1` and a `BackgroundWorker` to `Form2`.  Add this code to `Form1`:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Display a dialogue while the specified method is executed on a secondary thread.
    Dim dialogue As New Form2(New Action(Of Integer)(AddressOf Pause), New Object() {5})

    dialogue.ShowDialog()

    MessageBox.Show("Work complete!")
End Sub

Private Sub Pause(period As Integer)
    'Pause for the specified number of seconds.
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(period * 1000)
End Sub
```

and this code to `Form2`:

```
Private ReadOnly method As [Delegate]
Private ReadOnly args As Object()

Public Sub New(method As [Delegate], args As Object())
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    Me.method = method
    Me.args = args
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    'Execute the specified method with the specified arguments.
    method.DynamicInvoke(args)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    'Close the dialogue when the work is complete.
    Close()
End Sub
```

Run the project and click the `Button` on the startup form.  You'll see the dialogue displayed while the work is executed and then disappear when it's done.  The dialogue is written in such a way that it can be used to invoke any method with any arguments.  It's the caller that gets to define what the work to be performed is.

In this particular case, the "work" is a simple sleep but you can put anything you like in there.  Just note that it is executed on a secondary thread so no direct interaction with the UI is allowed.  If you need UI interaction then that could be accomplished but you'd need slightly more complex code.  Note that the code as it is also does not allow for returning a result from the executed method, but you could support that fairly easily too.

Comment: If you are following along with this example, don't be concerned if you see red squiggles after pasting the code in Form1. This will disappear when you paste the code for Form2 which contains the parameterized Constructor for Form2.